# DaVinci Resolve delivers distorted 1920x1080 videos

Tags: video-editor, davinci-resolve

I'm new to DaVinci Resolve, and new to video editing too.
I used the newest version of DaVinci Resolve 16. I used OBS Studio to record some game/desktop footage at 1920x1080 and 30 fps. I then imported said footage into DaVinci with no issues and edited it. Everything was normal. However, after rendering, the result looks wrong (see the image below)
[image]

The output video canvas seems to be 1920x1080, but the actually image is squeezed.

My project settings for the timeline are:
- 1920x1080.
- Pixel ratio is square -- I have a few options (square, 16:9, 4:3 and cinema), but when I choose 1920x1080, the 16:9 and 4:3 checkboxes stay dark and I can't select them.

I tried also to change the "Clip attributes", which include PAL 16:9 and NTSC 16:9. None of it worked.
I used the "Youtube 1080P" rendering option preset.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a limitation of the free version.  Check all the project and system settings in Davinci. There are a lot of them - maybe one of them is set to something other than 1920x1080

Comment: I figured out the problem. I was confused about the project settings of 1920*1080 with pixel ratio "square", I thought this is somehow wrong, but I was wrong. The "square" is just the pixel width height ratio, not related to the 1920*1080 setting, I didn't know the pixels can be rectangle.   So the problem is, I set imported footages pixel ratio 16:9 and project pixel ratio square, so the export result is not rignt, when I change the footage pixel to square, result is fine.

Comment: You can answer your own question here. You should. It improves visibillity. Re: pixel aspect ratio; until you're spending >$10K on anamorphic lenses, or unless you're using ancient camcorders, you can leave this at square.